# Image processing in ARM (angstrom)

Tags: c++, linux, matlab, embedded, arm

I'm new to ARM and linux in general but I have eclipse set up for programming my beaglebone black (running angstrom). I want to process an image (local file) and then use the processed image information to turn on/off some LEDs.

What's the most best/most efficient way to process images with my setup? Should I make some script to process the image in Matlab or linux equivalent? If so how would I get the information from those programs into my c++ program? Or should I simply process the image in c++ (probably more difficult)?

Comment: The answer HIGHLY depends on what processing you want to do (how complicated is it?), how often (does "speed" matter?) Also, what format is the image?

Comment: @MatsPetersson See my reply to npinti below; I would prefer to do it as fast as possible--hoping I might be able to expand into animated images later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This highly depends on what do you mean by *process*. If you want to do something complicated, I would recommend [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) since it offers a vast range of functionalities you can use to process your images.

That being said, if by *process* you mean extract text from images, you could take a look at [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) which is an open source OCR. If you will be going for an OCR, you could use OpenCV to do some pre-processing to make the text extraction process easier and more succesful.

If I am understanding you correctly, then you could take a look at [this](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/photo-to-colored-dot-patterns-with-opencv/) tutorial which should do what you are after (you start with an image and end up with a pixellated version of it).

Comment: Not sure if what I want to do will be complex or not. What I want to do is take an image and make it into pixel art (lose lots of detail and represent left over detail in small blocks); basically what this guy is doing in reverse :http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=23046 then all I want to do is get the color of each block and the x and y coordinates so I know the location of the block. What I want to end up doing is making an LED array representing the image as best it can.